# Insert boolean + results to mysqlDB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Writing a section of a long form to add data to MySQL database and in this form
a boolean checkbox that allows a section to show or hide and I need to insert this boolean to database with the other data

Later I need to get this data from database and show it in front end....
So it will say 
*Yes* (section is true and showing) + the rest of data in the section

**My problem is in boolean checkbox to insert it as "YES allowed" to retrieve it later and say "Yes it's Allowed + data"** .. I know it's easy but I'm at point of complete confusion

```
                        <label>Pets Allowed:</label>
                        <input class="form-pine" type="checkbox" name="pets" id="petscheck" value="<?php if(isset($result->dogs_permit)){ echo $result->dogs_permit; } ?>" onchange="valueChanged()"><br>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function valueChanged() {
                      if (document.getElementById('petscheck').checked) {
                          document.getElementById("petsshowhide").style.display = 'block';
                      } else {
                        document.getElementById("petsshowhide").style.display = 'none';
                      }
                    }
                    </script>

             <div class="col-pine-2" id="petsshowhide" style="display:none;">
                        <label>Pets fees:</label>
                        <select class="form-pine" name="dogs-fees">
                            <option value="">Select Option</option>
                            <option value="Inclusive"<?php if(isset($result->dogs_fees) && $result->dogs_fees == '0'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Inclusive</option>
                            <option value="Additional Charge"<?php if(isset($result->dogs_fees) && $result->dogs_fees == '1'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Additional Charge</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>pets Fees:</label>
                        <input class="form-pine" type="number" name="pets-price" value="<?php if(isset($result->dogs_price)){ echo $result->dogs_price; } ?>">
                        <label>currency:</label>
                        <select class="form-pine" name="dogs-curr">
                            <option value="">Select currency</option>
                            <option value="USD"<?php if(isset($result->dogs_curr) && $result->dogs_curr == 'USD'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>USD</option>
                            <option value="EUR"<?php if(isset($result->dogs_curr) && $result->dogs_curr == 'EUR'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>EUR</option>
                        </select>

            </div>
```

function add

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitpineapple'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_pine = $wpdb->prefix . 'ppf_admin';
    $dogs_permit = $_POST['pets'];
    $dogs_fees = $_POST['dogs-fees'];
    $dogs_price = $_POST['pets-price'];
    $dogs_curr = $_POST['dogs-curr'];
    if(isset($_POST['adds_pineapple'])){
        $pid = $_POST['adds_pineapple'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_pine (dogs_permit, dogs_fees, dogs_price, dogs_curr) VALUES ($dogs_permit, '$dogs_fees', $dogs_price, '$dogs_curr')";
            if($wpdb->query($sql)){
                echo'<div class="success-msg">Save Successfully</div>';
            }else{
                echo'<div class="errorcss">Something went wrong!</div>';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store *pets*  as `1` if it is selected or `0` if it is not selected in the table. Or in a parent table.

You will have `$_POST['pets']` available when it is selected. You can check for this with `isset($_POST['pets'])` and get `1` or `0` with `$dogs_permit=isset($_POST['pets'])? 1 : 0;`